# FLUTTER RESTFUL API WITH DIO PACKAGE NOT RETURNING DATA

Tags: flutter, api, dart, dio

please I have an Issue, Restful API using the dio package.
I have no error in my debug console but I don't get any data (the article) on my device, just the circularprogressindicator rolling.

This is the API class

```
class NewsApiServices {
  static String _apiKey = "033a693c19e440ad8d1bc53afc769d35";
  String _url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-04-25&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=$_apiKey"; 

  final _dio = Dio();

  Future <List<Article>> fetchNewsArticle() async {
    try{
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
      NewsResponse newsResponse = NewsResponse.fromJson(response.data);
      return newsResponse.articles;
    } on DioError catch (e){
      print(e);
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I called it

```
Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder <List<Article>> (
                  future: NewsApiServices().fetchNewsArticle(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if (!snapshot.hasData){
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                    } else{
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(snapshot.data![index].title),
                          );
                        }
                        );
                    }
                  }
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: You should also check ```snapshot.hasError```.

Comment: Most likely NewsResponse.fromJson fails, please share a code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not decoding your raw json data to dart objects, so nothing is being rendered because dart does not understand what you are giving to it.

This is your code

```
class NewsApiServices {
  static String _apiKey = "033a693c19e440ad8d1bc53afc769d35";
  String _url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-04-25&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=$_apiKey"; 

  final _dio = Dio();

  Future <List<Article>> fetchNewsArticle() async {
    try{
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
      NewsResponse newsResponse = NewsResponse.fromJson(response.data);
      return newsResponse.articles;
    } on DioError catch (e){
      print(e);
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Editted Code

```
class NewsApiServices {
  static String _apiKey = "033a693c19e440ad8d1bc53afc769d35";
  String _url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2022-04-25&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=$_apiKey"; 

  final _dio = Dio();

  Future <List<Article>> fetchNewsArticle() async {
    try{
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url);
      NewsResponse newsResponse = NewsResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data));
      return newsResponse.articles;
    } on DioError catch (e){
      print(e);
      throw Exception(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Now depending on what you used to make your model class, I'm assuming you have a one-liner that is `fromJson`, change it to `fromMap`.